# Java binary search recursive

Tags: java, compiler-errors, binary-search

I have to implement Binary search method which finds if value is or isn't in array. I have to use recurse.

```
public static boolean searchBin(int[] array, int x, int l, int r) {

        int center;

        center =(l+r) / 2;
        if ( x > array[center] )
        {
            l = center+1;
        }   
        else 
        {
            r = center-1;
        }

        if ( array[center] == x )
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if ( l<=r )
            {
                searchBin(array,x,l,r); 
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Missing return statement

Thanks.

Comment: Because there exists a path on which you don't `return` anything. But the method should `return` something..

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return searchBin(array,x,l,r); ` ?

Answer (score 2):

This is because one of the possible path of execution could lead to none of your return statements: in the last `if`, if the condition `l<=r` is `true`, nothing is returned (you only call recursively your method).

You might want to add the `return` keyword before your recursive call:

```
return searchBin(array,x,l,r);
```

This way, your method will (in this case) return whatever the recursive call returns.

Answer (score 2):

This is because as the error suggests "not all paths return a value".

This is the possible problem:

```
searchBin(array,x,l,r);
```

A fix will be:

```
return searchBin(array,x,l,r);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no return where you have the recursive call to

```
searchBin
```